# Migrate from JIRA to Gemini

Tags: jira, gemini

From reading the Gemini documentation, it looks as though I just export the JIRA database and then use the Gemini import wizard.  We have several projects in JIRA and I need to import each project separately into Gemini.  I don't see a way to do this cleanly.  Does anybody have experience with doing this and can help me out?  I am using the Subversion plugin, will I loose that information upon import or can I retain that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have used Jira 5 and tried that import which didn't work for us. We have contacted Gemini and sent them our Jira database and they converted it all fully for us.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this documentation: http://docs.countersoft.com/importing-existing-data/ Because that refers to an Excel or CSV import, not XML or SQL from the JIRA database. You might be able to find all issues in a JIRA project, then export as Excel and try importing that into Gemini

Comment: I found that documentation, was hoping that somebody had written a script or something that would have streamlined the process.